# ClientError: Unable to parse csv K-means in SageMarker

Tags: csv, k-means, amazon-sagemaker

I try to execute k-means in SageMaker. I have myFile.csv upload in S3 and when I create my 'training job':

[image]

And I get the following error: "ClientError: Unable to parse csv: rows 1-5000, file /opt/ml/input/data/train/myFile.csv"

I try to remove the header, using less data...

Answer (score 0):

Please try using 'text/csv;label_size=0' instead of 'text/csv' for Tipo de contenido

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data in your CSV is well-formed? Can check the contents using a CSV reader? How about posting a small sample of the data for us to check?